# How to interpret single quote used as input to java main method as single quote and not interpreting it as the start and the end of one argument?

Tags: java, string, single-quotes

I'm learning about collections in java and there is a program that takes inputs (args) and stores the unique words in a `Set` and the duplicated ones in another, when I was playing around I typed single quotes (') in the inputs and the text in between each two was interpreted as a single argument, so I want to know is there a way to interpret single or even double quotes as a part of a text or argument?

I have escaped the single quotes and this works as expected, but how to make this from inside the program (not depending on escaping the quotes)?

```java
public final static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet<String> uniques = new HashSet<String>();
        HashSet<String> dups = new HashSet<String>();

        for (String arg : args) {
            if (!uniques.add(arg)) {
                dups.add(arg);
            }
        }
        System.out.format("unique inputs: %s%n", uniques);
        System.out.format("duplicated inputs: %s%n", dups);
    }
```

Comment: The command line arguments (arguments to `main`) are passed in by the shell. How the shell parses them is not in Java's control.

Comment: This is true on Unix, but not on Windows.

Comment: So the only thing I can do on Unix like systems is to surround the inputs by double quotes in case I don't use them in my input text or escape all the single quotes ?

Comment: It's actually the only thing you can do on either platform, because while it's [under Java's control](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/6bab0f539fba8fb441697846347597b4a0ade428/src/java.base/windows/native/libjli/cmdtoargs.c#L28) on Windows, the JDK will parse it to make it the same on both platforms and don't give user code a say in the matter.

Comment: There are technically ways to get around it, but they are extremely awkward and fragile because they try to fight the system. It's much easier, better, faster and more robust to do what all other tools do. Either require escaping and pass them as arguments, or read it from `System.in` without escaping.

Comment: If you need to custom-parse arguments, take the input at runtime rather than at the command line. It doesn't really work the other way around.

Comment: @thatotherguy your last comment is a good answer.

Comment: @trvlr yes, I used `Scanner` with `System.in` as @thatotherguy said, and taking arguments at runtime and I think the problem is solved.